# How the char data type is being distinguished from signed or unsigned?

Tags: c

I am currently in the process of learning C with the K&R's book - 2nd edition.

Until now I've understood that there are 3 types of `char` data type (8 bit): *plain* `char` which is mostly signed by default but could be unsigned depending the platform, `unsigned char` and `signed char`.

The bit pattern of `-1` in `signed char` is `11111111` and the hex is `0xFF`.

The bit pattern of `255` in `unsigned char` is `11111111` and the hex is `0xFF`.

*So, both are the same? There is no sign bit to represent that it's either signed or unsigned?* **My question is how it's being distinguished one from another?** I am obviously missing something here but what? :-)

For `int` (4 bytes) there is a similar example:

`signed int` value of `255` is represented  in the bit pattern as `00000000 00000000 00000000 11111111`

`unsigned int` value of `255` is represented in the bit pattern as `00000000 00000000 00000000 11111111`

Again both are the same. So, how the system will find out that it's either `signed` or `unsigned` int data type?

Comment: C is a typed language. The same bit-pattern can mean different things depending on the declared type of the variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no difference except in how they're used. When you tell your compiler that a variable is `signed` or `unsigned`, it knows to use signed or unsigned instructions when performing mathematical operations on it. When you use `printf`, you explicitly provide format codes that tell the function whether the argument is signed or unsigned (e.g. `%u` vs. `%d`). By the time the program is running, yep, just looking at the registers and memory, you can't tell the difference between `-1` (as a `signed char`) and `255` (as an `unsigned char`) on systems with `CHAR_BIT == 8` and two's complement math, but the program has baked that knowledge into how it *works* with the otherwise indistinguishable values.

It's the same way that a pointer width `0` and `NULL` behave (or any other equivalent number and pointer pattern); they're both just a bunch of zero bits, but numeric zero is manipulated and used as a number, while `NULL` is manipulated as a pointer. The bits are the same, the way the compiler and APIs use them is different.

Comment: So, in a few words: when the C code is compiled then the compiler sets instructions and after that when the program is executed, the system will know if it's either `signed` or `unsigned`, right?

Comment: @Plar625 yes exactly.

Comment: @Plar625: Well, the system doesn't *know* anything at all. It just executes the instructions it's given, and the instructions just *use* the data as signed or unsigned. If the compiler barfed, and used half signed instructions and half unsigned when it was supposed to be purely one or the other, the *system* wouldn't notice or care, but your *results* might be incorrect.

Comment: @ShadowRanger - I got it. Basically there are instructions set on the compiling process but we DON'T see them unless we debug it in assembly most likely, is that correct?. :-) Also, how is it possible the compiler to barf, I mean how it will use half signed and/or half unsigned? I appreciate your help.Thank you!

Comment: The null example isn't very good. `NULL` might be defined to `0`; and also, the null pointer value might not have the same representation as integer `0`

Comment: @Plar625: It would mean a buggy compiler. The example was illustrative, I wouldn't expect to actually see a compiler do it. That said, the integer promotion rules for C are not always intuitive, so you do see mixed signedness arithmetic that just happens to work anyway sometimes.

Comment: @ShadowRanger - I see, and lastly regarding the instructions .. we don't see them upon compiling but they are visible debugging it on assembly level? Thank you a lot for your help!

Comment: @Plar625: Yup. Though many compilers provide a switch to compile code to the machine's assembly instead of compiling to the final binary.